# How can I rename columns based on matching data in another dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes where the labeling of products does not always match:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Product 1':['Shoes'],'Product 1 Price':[25],'Product 2':['Shirts'],'Product 2 Price':[50],'Product 3':['Pants'],'Product 3 Price':24})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Product 1':['Shirts'],'Product 1 Price':[60],'Product 2':['Pants'],'Product 2 Price':[30],'Product 3':['Shoes'],'Product 3 Price':14})
```

df1

| Product 1 | Product 1 Price | Product 2 | Product 2 Price | Product 3 | Product 3 Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Shoes | 25 | Shirts | 50 | Pants | 24 |

df2

| Product 1 | Product 1 Price | Product 2 | Product 2 Price | Product 3 | Product 3 Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Shirts | 60 | Pants | 30 | Shoes | 14 |

Since I need to do an apples to apples comparison on the data, how can I rename the columns in df1 so that the product numbers are the same in df1 and df2?

Ideally, the end result would be a df1 that looks like:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'Product 1':['Shirts'],'Product 1 Price':[50],'Product 2':['Pants'],'Product 2 Price':[24],'Product 3':['Shoes'],'Product 3 Price':25})
```

| Product 1 | Product 1 Price | Product 2 | Product 2 Price | Product 3 | Product 3 Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Shirts | 50 | Pants | 24 | Shoes | 25 |

Comment: Did you pivot your data in this format because things are easier if you have one column for products and one for prices?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is how the source data is coming to me

Comment: Are the products unique or can you have duplicate products?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the output you are looking for but may make things easier for comparison between the two frames; however, there are certain assumptions - e.g., that `Product n` is always followed by `Product n Price` in the original frames

```
# stack your frames
df1_stack = df1.stack()
df2_stack = df2.stack()

# create new frames columns for every other row
d1 = pd.DataFrame([df1_stack[::2].values,
                   df1_stack[1::2].values]).T

d2 = pd.DataFrame([df2_stack[::2].values,
                   df2_stack[1::2].values]).T

# merge them together and rename columns
m_df = d1.merge(d2, on=0) # change the merge "how" param based on your needs
m_df.columns = ['Products', 'Price_df1', 'Price_df2'] 

  Products Price_df1 Price_df2
0    Shoes        25        14
1   Shirts        50        60
2    Pants        24        30
```

Now if you want to calculate the price difference we can do

```
m_df['Price_diff'] = m_df['Price_df1'].sub(m_df['Price_df2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```py
import pandas as pd

# setup
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Product 1':['Shoes'],'Product 1 Price':[25],'Product 2':['Shirts'],'Product 2 Price':[50],'Product 3':['Pants'],'Product 3 Price':24})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Product 1':['Shirts'],'Product 1 Price':[60],'Product 2':['Pants'],'Product 2 Price':[30],'Product 3':['Shoes'],'Product 3 Price':14})

# concat the data frames
df = pd.concat(
    objs=[df1, df2],
    ignore_index=True,
)

df = (
    # add "Name" to the end of the Product columns so we 
    # can differentiate from "Price"
    df.set_axis(
        labels=(
            df.columns.str.replace(
                # regex pattern that grabs the 
                # columns names that say "Product \d+"
                # and don't end with "Price"
                pat="(Product \d+)(?! Price)",
                repl=r"\1 Name",
                regex=True,
            )
            # split the columns on whitespace and 
            # expand so we have a MultiIndex
            .str.split(expand=True)
        ),
        axis="columns",
    )
    # stack the top two column levels 
    # ("Product", "Number")
    .stack([0, 1])
    # drop the product number
    .droplevel([-2, -1], axis="index")
    # pivot the product names into their 
    # own columns
    .pivot(columns="Name")
)

print(df)
```

```
     Price             
Name Pants Shirts Shoes
0       24     50    25
1       30     60    14
```